# Can I use fypp to write generic Fortran containers?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, fortran

Is it possible to write generic Fortran containers (e.g. a list or a binary tree) with a Fortran preprocessor such as fypp, similar to C++ templates?
If so, how would that work?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Yes it is certainly possible. I suppose there is an example in the manual but it is also probably possible to show something short here. CP2K seems to be using exactly that https://www.cp2k.org/dev:templates https://tcevents.chem.uzh.ch/event/12/contributions/57/attachments/36/106/presentation.pdf (slide 9)

Comment: Actually, I found a question that asks the same thing. I even provided a short FYPP example there some time ago. I linked some more questions that show related options. I suggest to always search first.

Comment: Thank you, looks like that's what I was looking for.

Comment: If you have some specific problem when implementing the stuff in fypp, feel welcome to ask a question.